# When to use "leads into"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

When using "lead", when to use "into" and when to use "to". For example:

> The implementation vulnerability leads the machine into using a weaker mode

OR

> The implementation vulnerability leads the machine to use a weaker mode

Comment: As a native speaker, the second one sounds much better but the first one still works.

Comment: Could you write at least a full sentence? Out of context, I don't get how someone/something *leads* a machine.

Comment: @ user3169 edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the verb "lead", if you are talking about abstract ideas or causation ("this led to that"), use "to".

(Except for some fixed idioms like "lead into danger".)

If you are talking about physical spaces which are enclosed (a room, a car, a cave), use "into". Do this even if the enclosure is not a physical barrier ("into a forest", "into Heaven", "into his yard").

If you are talking about physical spots you can point at (a door, a chair), use "to". Do this even if the spot is a very big object ("lead to the factory", "lead to the river").